# fp alignment in tables

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, fp

Can anyone explain why the output from these two entries is different? Does anyone know how to make the second one match the first?

```
\documentclass{article}
\include{fp}
\newcommand\entryOne[1]{
\ifnum #1 = 100 #1 \fi
}
\newcommand\entryTwo[1]{
\FPeval{\result}{#1}
\ifnum \result = 100 \result \fi
}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\hline
Entry 1 & \entryOne{100} \\
Entry 2 & \entryTwo{100} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: my beautiful table]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeX is not “free form” and spaces are significant: remember that it's a program for typesetting.

You have several spaces in your commands:

```
\newcommand\entryOne[1]{
\ifnum #1 = 100 #1 \fi
}
```

The end of line after the brace counts as a space; also the space after the second `#1` counts. It's true that in a table cell both are removed, but it's not a good reason for having them in the definition. Fixed definition:

```
\newcommand\entryOne[1]{%
  \ifnum #1 = 100 #1\fi
}
```

Note that the space after the first `#1` is ignored by syntax rule, like the one after `100`.

Second definition:

```
\newcommand\entryTwo[1]{
\FPeval{\result}{#1}
\ifnum \result = 100 \result \fi
}
```

You have a space after `{`, and one at the end of the second line. This is the one that's not removed, because it isn't at the start of a cell, causing the cell to contain `<space>100`, which explains the misalignment.

Fixed definition:

```
\newcommand\entryTwo[1]{%
  \FPeval{\result}{#1}%
  \ifnum \result = 100 \result \fi
}
```

Note that spaces after control sequences are ignored during reading.

Final remarks: `\include{fp}` is wrong, it should be `\usepackage{fp}`; the indentation I used makes clearer where the replacement text starts and ends.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}

\newcommand\entryOne[1]{%
  \ifnum #1 = 100 #1\fi
}
\newcommand\entryTwo[1]{%
  \FPeval{\result}{#1}%
  \ifnum \result = 100 \result \fi
}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\hline
Entry 1 & \entryOne{100} \\
Entry 2 & \entryTwo{100} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]